# High CPU & MEMORY usage during online video play

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, cpu-usage

I have multiple questions related to high CPU and memory usage during play of live video in internet.

Problems:

CPU at 100% and RAM at 90% during playing online video like Amazon Prime, ZEE5, Netflix. Except ZEE5, others are still watchable as there is no lag, but ZEE5 causes videos to freeze.

Computer System:
4 year old. Gigabyte GA-N3050M main board with onboard Celeron Dual core CPU @1.6 GHZ. 4GB DDR3 RAM @1600MHz. A-DATA Ultimate SU650 3D NAND 120GB SSD. Sony 21 inch TV as monitor. Monitor connection is VGA. Motherboard supports a maximum resolution of 1920x1200@60 Hz in VGA mode and a maximum resolution of 3840x2160@30 Hz in HDMI mode. I use VGA. It has one  1 x PCI Express x4 slot, running at x1

Questions:

1. The motherboard is capable of descent resolution then why the CPU starts to struggle at playing online video?
2. If I connect the monitor to HDMI port will that lower the burden on CPU and RAM ?
3. Will it be possible to install a graphics card on this board and if yes, will that make the video playing smoother and lower the CPU and RAM usage?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because the CPU is having to decode some/all of the video stream data. Video codecs have varying amounts of demand on a CPU.
2. Unlikely.
3. Yes, look got a PCI-e x4 card like a Geforce GT 710. It should reduce the load on the CPU & RAM.